# What type of KML data is being displayed in this picture?

Tags: geospatial, kml, google-earth

I'm trying to make a KML that displays the red lines in a similar fashion. I would like to use it for training on setting up satellites for television.

I'm not sure how to create this or what it's called. I know the Azimuth, Altitude and distance information is being displayed. I have been searching for hours and I can't find anything on how to do this or what it is called.

http://38north.org/thaad031016_section3/fig1_thaad-2/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is a tessellate KML. I needed to increased the altitude for each point manually by editing the file. I was able to achieve the end state this way.